# What is the differences between Airy irregular wave model and Statistical waves models of Tessendorf?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, oceanography

I've read [the article of Tessendorf](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.161.9102&rep=rep1&type=pdf) which implements the ocean based on a statistical waves models, I have the impression that this is the method used globally in video games and real time application. However, I saw in another software an implementation of [the Airy irregular wave model](http://theory.frydom.org/src/environment/waves/linear_wave_theory/wave_theory.html). But the two methods produce approximately the same equations.

Can someone tell me what are the differences between these two theories?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the pages you referenced, I see two clear statements.

> Even before Airy's linear theory, Gerstner derived a nonlinear
> trochoidal wave theory in 1802, which however is not irrotational

> Airy wave theory is a linear theory for the propagation of waves

Comment: Yes I saw these differences, but I don't see what are the differences in the equation which represents the waves. Sorry I'll edit my question to make it more clear on this point.